# MVC second web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, web-config

Whenever I create an MVC web application their is a second `Web.config` file in the solution. It is inside the `Views` folder.

If I remove it, `BadThings` happen. 
But any time, things are needed to be added to a Web.config (nuget packages, connection strings, app settings) it only ever goes into the root `Web.Config`, and I try to never make changes to this second beast.

Also, it was just one other headache when needing to upgrade apps from MVC3 -> MVC4 -> MVC5

What is the `Views` `Web.Config` used for, and what sort of changes are ever made for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this has been asked before, but the file is there to ensure nobody can access a view without going through the controller. If you remove it, someone can hack to see your code, which might give them some information on what you are doing (especially if someone on your team is sloppy).

In general, you don't make changes, as it is just there to add the extra security.